# Scripting many helper calls in the Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scripting, console

I'm looking to write a script which calls a helper many times within the Rails console with a different argument for each call and outputs the return value to a file. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone finds this message...

Yes, it's possible with a simple Ruby script. Just write something that makes the calls and run it in the console.